# How to pass array of shortstring to a method

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-2007

I would like to make a procedure that take array of shortstring as argument

```
procedure f(const a, b: Array of shortstring);
```

I would like to call this with arrays of known length and shortstrings of known length e.g.

```
var
  A, B: array[1..2] of string[5];
  C, D: array[1..40] of string[12];
begin
  f(A,B);
  f(C,D);
end;
```

This result in an compiler error E2008 Incompatible types.
Why is that? Can I write a procedure that can take arrays of shortstring (any length of arrays/strings)?

**Why use shortstring?**

The shortstings are fields in an existing record. There are alot of these record with thousand of shortstrings. In an effort to migrate data from turbo power B-Tree Filer to SQL databases one step is to convert the record to a dataset, and the back to a record, to confirm all fields are converted correctly both directions. I have been using `CompareMem` on the records to check this, but it does not provide enough information as to which field a conversion error is in. Thus a small program was created, which from the record definition can generate code to compare the two records. It was for this code generator I needed a function to compare shortstrings. It ended up using `CompareMem` on the shortstrings.

Comment: Why do you want to use shortstrings? For the life of me I can't work out when they are useful.

Comment: Just use an array of string. Never mind about declaring the length. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: @David: I found one good use for them a while ago. I was getting difficult-to-trace memory leaks in some heavily recursive tree-based parser code.  By changing the symbol object from a **string** for the symbol name to a `ShortString`, the name showed up inline in the memory dump in FastMM's FullDebugMode report, making it much easier to find the problem.

Comment: You can make this much easier on yourself by not using ShortString. Declaring a dynamic array type and using that type will work much more easily; you can find the number if items using `Length` and the bounds will always be `0 to High(ArrayVar)`, and pass any argument of that type to your method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Updated question with why shortstrings are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation I've used the following:

```
type
  TOpenArrayOfOpenString = record
  strict private
    FSizeOfString: Integer;
    FpStart: PChar;
    FArrayLength: Integer;
    function GetItemPtr(AIndex: Integer): PShortString;
  public
    constructor Init(var AFirstString: Openstring; AArrayLength: Integer);
    function Equals(const AArray: TOpenArrayOfOpenString): Boolean;

    property SizeOfString: Integer read FSizeOfString;
    property pStart: PChar read FpStart;
    property ArrayLength: Integer read FArrayLength;
    property ItemPtrs[AIndex: Integer]: PShortString read GetItemPtr; default;
  end;

{ TOpenArrayOfOpenString }

constructor TOpenArrayOfOpenString.Init(var AFirstString: Openstring; AArrayLength: Integer);
begin
  FSizeOfString := SizeOf(AFirstString);
  FpStart := @AFirstString[0]; // incl. length byte!
  FArrayLength := AArrayLength;
end;

function TOpenArrayOfOpenString.Equals(const AArray: TOpenArrayOfOpenString): Boolean;
begin
  Result := CompareMem(pStart, AArray.pStart, SizeOfString * ArrayLength);
end;

function TOpenArrayOfOpenString.GetItemPtr(AIndex: Integer): PShortString;
begin
  Result := PShortString(pStart + AIndex * SizeOfString);
end;
```

You could use it like this:

```
procedure f(const a: TOpenArrayOfOpenString);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Pred(a.ArrayLength) do
    Writeln(a[i]^);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: array[1..2] of string[5];
  C: array[1..40] of string[12];
begin
  f(TOpenArrayOfOpenString.Init(A[1], Length(A)));
  f(TOpenArrayOfOpenString.Init(C[1], Length(C)));
end;
```

It's not as elegant as a solution built into the language could be and it is a bit hacky as it relies on the fact/hope/... that the strings in the array are laid out contiguously. But it worked for me for some time now.

Answer (score 7):

A ShortString is 0 to 255 characters long. The length of a ShortString can change dynamically, but memory is a statically allocated 256 bytes, the first byte stores the length of the string, and the remaining 255 bytes are available for characters, whilist string[5] declared in this way allocate only as much memory as the type requires (5 byte + 1 byte for length).
you could use type

```
type
    MyString = string[5];
...
procedure f(const a, b: Array of MyString);
...

var
    A, B: array[1..2] of MyString;
begin
    f(A,B);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It only solves the problem for string[5] though. I updated my question to better show what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @MGH That's impossible. array of string[5] and array of string[12] are not compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

```
   type
      shortStrings =array[1..2] of string[5];  
    ...
    a,b : shortString;
    ..
    procedure rock(a,b : shortStrings);
    ..
```

Answer (score -1):

You are combining two different kinds of open array.

First, there is the classic Turbo Pascal "string" (also called "openstring" in Delphi IIRC) which is essentially string[255]. As string[255] is a superset of all shortstrings, the open array aspect simply converts all shortstring types to it.

The "array of xx" syntax is the Delphi (4+?) open array. It is an open array of any type, not just strings, and the syntax to call it is f(nonarrayparam,[arrayelement0,arrayelement1]);

Somehow you seem to mix both syntaxes, and even aggrevate it by adding CONST which sollicits pass by reference and excludes conversions.

I think you assume shortstring has an performance advantage. It has, in some cases. Open array is not one of those cases. Not even in TP :-)